# cambiar el tamaño de imagen con un backgraund-blend sin media query

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo un duda quiero poner una imagen usando backgraund-blend y quiero que cambie de tamaño mientras que cambie el tamaño de tu navegado  pero me sale un ploblemas que en los margenes top y bottom sale el filtro . 
el codigo html es el siguiente

```css
  
 .secti {
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
  }

.portada-sport {
    max-width: 651px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 433px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #b1d0ff, #fcbcf1), url(../bebe.jpg);
    background-blend-mode: hard-light;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="css/stylo.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/portada.css">
   
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 
            <div class="secti">
            <div class="portada-sport"></div>
        </div>
        
</body>

</html>
```

El problemas persiste cuando en el backgraund-imagen:url(el nombre del archivo.jpg)a la hora de cambiar el tamaño de tu navegador cambia uniformente el tamaño de la imagen pero sale el filtro de blend-mode:hard- light por el margin top y margin bottom,

podria ayudarme  sin usar MEDIA QUERY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar cambiando la instrucción **background-size**;

```
    background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Voy ha probarlo luego , de toda maneras creo que de tanto probar ya lo hice y no funcionó pero de todas manera lo voy a intentarlo de nuevo

Comment: hola de nuevo lo acabo de poner backgraund-size: cover; y me sale cortado cuando reduzco el navegador

Comment: hola estoy dando vuelta a la cabeza y no hay maneras de hacerlo en cambio como esta puesto si que sale con la etiqueta de background-size:  100%. Me sale lo que quiero ("que cuando reduzco el navegador se adapte a la pantalla ")pero el probremas es que sale uno margen de arriba y el de abajo  unos espacios que no quiero  en cambio con el Cover  se me corta la imagen  no se me adapta al navegador